# How i can sort a list python maya

Tags: python, list, sorting, filter, maya

I have a list [0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5] and I would like to sort it to keep only values ​​that are not equal to 0.

```
from maya import cmds

def splitShape():
    a = cmds.ls(sl=True)

    if len(a)<=1:
        cmds.warning( "Select 2 target")

    elif len(a) >= 2:
        #cmds.warning( "SPLIIIIIT")
        cmds.select( a[0] , r = True)
        Vertex = a[0] + '.vtx[*]'
        cmds.select(Vertex)

        #_____LIST______
        b = cmds.getAttr(a[0] + 'Shape' + '.pnts[*]' + '.pntz')
        #print b

        if len(b) == 0:
            print ok
        elif len(b) != 0:
            cmds.setAttr( a[0] + 'Shape' + '.pnts[*]' + '.pntz' , 0)
```

Tanks :)

Comment: Is `maya` relevant to your question? You seem to be asking how to sort and filter. Are both of these things you don't know how to do? Have you done a search to see whether there are other questions on those subjects?

Comment: If you Google the phrases "Python sort" and "Python filter", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter a list keeping only values not equal to zero:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0.5 ,0.5]
list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, a))
# [0.5, 0.5]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0.5 ,0.5]

b = [x for x in a if a != 0] # list comprehension
```